# Indices of non-number and zero values cells in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataset

I have dataset (bigger than this part) where I store float numbers. But some of the data is missing. How can I find all of the indices where data is missing or has non-number value? I was looking for similar questions on SO, but mostly it was about dropping rows, but probably similar question was asked before but I couldn't find it. I need to replace these values, so I need to identify them all.

I want to get indices of cells `[86,2], [87,2], [87,3]`. How can I easily retrieve them?

```
         0       1       2       3       4
85  1645.0  1596.0  1578.0  1567.0  1580.0
86  1554.0  1506.0     0.0  1466.0  1469.0
87  1588.0  1510.0    'ff'       0  1489.0
```

I include JSON if anyone needs to recreate example:

```
{"0":{"85":1645.0,"86":1554.0,"87":1588.0},"1":{"85":1596.0,"86":1506.0,"87":1510.0},"2":{"85":1578.0,"86":0.0,"87":'ff'},"3":{"85":1567.0,"86":1466.0,"87":0},"4":{"85":1580.0,"86":1469.0,"87":1489.0}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with optional parameter `errors='coerce'` to convert each series in dataframe to numeric type if possible otherwise the values which can not be converted are substituted with `NaN` values. Then you can create a mask `m` on the conditions where `d` is equal to `0` or `NaN`. Now using [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) you can stack the columns in mask `m` to multilevel index creating a series `s`. Now, filter this series `s` where the values are `True`. Thereafter you can get the required `indices` using `Series.index.tolist()`.

Use:

```
d = df.apply(lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s, errors="coerce"))
m = d.eq(0) | d.isna()
s = m.stack()
indices = s[s].index.tolist()
```

Intermediate Steps:

```
# print(d)
         0       1       2       3       4
85  1645.0  1596.0  1578.0  1567.0  1580.0
86  1554.0  1506.0     0.0  1466.0  1469.0
87  1588.0  1510.0     NaN     0.0  1489.0

# print(m)
       0      1      2      3      4
85  False  False  False  False  False
86  False  False   True  False  False
87  False  False   True   True  False

# print(s)
85  0    False
    1    False
    2    False
    3    False
    4    False
86  0    False
    1    False
    2     True
    3    False
    4    False
87  0    False
    1    False
    2     True
    3     True
    4    False
dtype: bool

# print(s[s])
86  2    True
87  2    True
    3    True
dtype: bool
```

Result:

```
# print(indices)

[('86', '2'), ('87', '2'), ('87', '3')]
```